# Getting MinDate instead of NULL

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am calling a stored procedure, and may expect a NULL back.

However, when I get to EntityFramework with the result, it seems that the result gets converted to a Min Date (01-01-0001).

```
    result.NextPaymentDate =
        (from c in Context.GetPaymentDatesForSchedule(source.id) where c.NextPaymentFlag select c.PaymentDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to make it NULL, if I get a NULL value from the sproc?

It seems 'dirty' doing something like:

```
    if (result.NextPaymentDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        result.NextPaymentDate = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `NextPaymentDate` property is not `nullable` in your model, if you make it `nullable` you will then get the `null` value instead of min date.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. It looks like I am stuck with DateTime.Min as the default, because it seems, default(DateTime) is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.